# So i want to build a function which returns a list with capitalized strings

Tags: python-3.x

This is working fine , but i want it to make it simpler than this

```
def convert(string_list):

    for i in range(len(string_list)):

      string_list[i] = string_list[i].upper()

    print(string_list)`enter code here`

string_list=['stack','overflow']

convert(string_list)
```

Thank you

Comment: If it's working, it might be better to post it to [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string_list = [x.upper() for x in string_list]
```

The above code will convert the list of all strings to uppercase.

If you need to print then you need to iterate over the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(string_list):
    for i in string_list:
    print(i.upper())

string_list=['stack','overflow']
convert(string_list)
```

If you just wanted to print, this is fine